# Where do I get the default css classes?

Tags: magento2, css

For example:

The css classes applied to primary buttons are .primary and .action
I know that because I inspected the element on a live page.

I want to find the css classes applied to buttons with icons but I don't have one on my page.

How can I tell what classes are applied to generic elements like inputs, etc?

Answer (score 0):

The classes for colors and buttons you can find in lib/web/css/source/lib